# SQL Conditional Commit - check on results even when there is no error

Tags: sql-server

I have a short query that I have created for un-canceling loads. I want to be able to just update the `@LoadID` and let it run and either commit at the end when successful or rollback if not successful.

I already have the updates in a transaction and can add a `try-catch` around it, but that won't always catch everything.

Basically I have to update one table and delete a row from another. Then I want to check to make sure that the update happened correctly and that the row was deleted. Then either rollback or commit.

Here is what I have currently:

```sql
    DECLARE @LoadID varchar(10) = 'LF2025391'

    SELECT * FROM dbo.SAR_AppointmentMaster AS SAR
    WHERE SAR.LoadID = @LoadID

    SELECT * FROM dbo.SAR_AppointmentTimes AS SAR
    WHERE SAR.AppointmentID IN(SELECT SAR.AppointmentID FROM dbo.SAR_AppointmentMaster AS SAR
                                WHERE SAR.LoadID = @LoadID)
    BEGIN TRY
    --/*
    BEGIN TRAN  --commit    rollback
    UPDATE dbo.SAR_AppointmentMaster
    SET dbo.SAR_AppointmentMaster.RecordStatus = 0
    WHERE dbo.SAR_AppointmentMaster.LoadID = @LoadID

    DELETE FROM dbo.SAR_AppointmentTimes
    FROM dbo.SAR_AppointmentTimes AS SAR2
    WHERE SAR2.AppointmentID IN(SELECT SAR.AppointmentID FROM dbo.SAR_AppointmentMaster AS SAR
                                WHERE SAR.LoadID = @LoadID)
        AND SAR2.DateType = 'CANCEL'
    --*/
        COMMIT
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK
    END CATCH

    SELECT * FROM dbo.SAR_AppointmentMaster AS SAR
    WHERE SAR.LoadID = @LoadID

    SELECT * FROM dbo.SAR_AppointmentTimes AS SAR
    WHERE SAR.AppointmentID IN(SELECT SAR.AppointmentID FROM dbo.SAR_AppointmentMaster AS SAR
                                WHERE SAR.LoadID = @LoadID)
```

It is possible that the update or the delete could fail and not be caught by the `try-catch` block. That's why I would like to use something like an `If` statement to make this check the update and delete before committing or to post an error and rollback. But I've not found anything that would work outside of a `select` in T-SQL.

Comment: update and delete should succeed or throw. Unless you mean that they didn't update anything because @loadid didn't refer to an existing record. In that case you can use [`@@ROWCOUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to verify how many rows they actually affected.

Comment: @GolezTrol, yes that is one possibility, if there isn't a matching `@LoadID` there won't be an update and so nothing to commit. I have had an instance once where it was updated and the row was not deleted even though everything came back as successful. So that is something else that I want to check for.

Comment: Eating the error and suppressing any useful feedback to the user / application when an error does occur will not be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you mention in the comments, it seems you just need to throw an exception inside `try` when it doesn't meet some expectation of yours, such as in the pattern below:

```
declare @exes table (x varchar(3));
insert @exes values ('xe'), ('exe'), ('xx'), ('x');

begin tran
begin try

    update @exes set x = 'x' where x <> 'ex';
    if @@rowcount = 0 throw 50000, 'Hey, no rows were updated', 1;

    delete @exes where x = 'ex';
    if @@rowcount = 0 throw 50000, 'Hey, no rows were deleted', 1;

    commit;

end try

begin catch
    rollback;
    throw;
end catch

select      *
from        @exes
```

Comment: This looks perfect thank you! I've not used `@@rowcount` before. I've been looking at it since the comments earlier.